# Missing 'Design new Report' on Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

Good day/night to all. I'm here because i couldnt find the exact answer to my question. google doesnt gave me the exact answer.
I already downloaded the [MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747), I've successfully integrated the reportviewer2012 in Visual Studio 2012 Express. When i drag the reportviewer and click the **Design new Report**, the report wizard doesnt appear.
Is this some kind of a bug? or something i forgot to add in visual studio 2012 express?
Please help me to solve this kind of issue.
Thank you